# Integration of chemical potential

Tags: thermodynamics, chemical-potential

I want to ask a question about chemical potential, $\mu$.

I dislike the use of integrals to describe quantities in thermodynamics. If we observe the definition of chemical potential for constant pressure:

$$\mu_i = \left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial N_i} \right)_{T, P, N_i \neq N_j}$$

which I can understand to mean *the change in Gibbs free energy G for a small change caused by the number of molecules of species **i***.

However, using some high school mathematics, I wondered if the following interpretation was valid.

If we consider that if $N_i = 0$, $G = 0$ and logically if $N_i = N_i$, $G = G_i$, integration by separation of variables will yield:

$$\partial G = \mu_i \times \partial N_i$$
$$\int_{0}^{G_i} \partial G = \mu_i\int_{0}^{N_i}\partial N_i$$

such that

$$G = \mu_i \times N_i$$

and hence

$$\mu_i = \frac{G}{N_i}$$
where the chemical potential of a species $\mu_i$ can better be expressed as the Gibbs free energy of a species $G$ divided by the amount of substance $N_i$.

Is this a more reasonable yet valid understanding of the chemical potential?

**EDIT** a similar equation is derived in [1].

[1] Chen, L. (2019). Chemical potential and Gibbs free energy. MRS Bulletin, 44(7), 520-523. doi:10.1557/mrs.2019.162

Comment: Why should be G=0 if Ni = 0? In such a case there would have been G=0 for all matter, as there is always some substance missing. Also, chemical potential is not constant, but is a function of Ni.

Comment: No, it´s simply a mathematical formula, which you have derived under a number of assumptions. Please explain how and under what circumstances this formula can be used! What does it *mean*?

Comment: At the very least you have assumed mu is independent of N. If it is not your third formula is invalid - mu should be inside the integration

Comment: See updated reference

Comment: Your last equation is the definition of mu for a pure substance. Otherwise as Ian explains you can't perform the integration as written since mu is a function of composition.